# How to prove that in a field with order $4$, $x^2 = x +1$ for $x$ different from $0$ and $1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

For a field $\mathbb{F}$ with order 4, prove that elements in $\mathbb{F}$ (except for $0$ and $1$) satisfies the equation:

$$
x^2 = x +1
$$

My thought is as followings:

Set $G = \{0,1,a,b\}$.
We can prove $Char \mathbb{F} = 2$ and consider $ab$ since the field has no zero divisors then $ab \neq 0$ and if $ab = a$ then $b = 1$ but $b \neq 1$, which implies $ab = 1$. Then consider $a^2$, since $a \neq b$ then $a^2 \neq 1$, by the same reason $a^2 \neq a,0$ then $a^2 = b$, then use the same way to consider $a+1$ we can get the answer.

But does there exist a easier way?

Comment: Your example is not a field: $(1,0).(0,1)=(0,0)$.

Comment: Note that $\Bbb{F}_2\oplus \Bbb{F}_2$ has zero divisors, $(1,0)\cdot (0,1)=(0,0)$, hence is not a field. But yes, certainly $x=0$ does not satisfy $x^2=x+1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Oh my god, thanks !

Comment: Similarly, the element $1$ does not satisfy the condition.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft sorry, I update the problem.

Comment: More details in [MSE question 2777107](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/277710) "Addition and multiplication in F_4".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is obviously not true for $x=0$ or $x=1$. But then the question looks a bit weird. Anyway,

Suppose that $x$ is neither $0$ nor $1$. We have $(x+1)(x^2 - x - 1) =(x+1)( x^2 - x + 1 ) = x^3 -1$. Since $F-\{0\}$ is cyclic of order $3$, $x^3 - 1 = 0$. Hence $x = -1 = 1$ or $x^2 = x+1$. So $x^2 = x+1$.

Comment: Thanks, your way is better!

Comment: And can you show me a concrete example of a field with order 4?

Comment: @R.Sherlock for instance $$\mathbb Z_2[x]/(x^2+1)$$where $(x^2+1)$ denotes the ideal in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$ generated by the polynomial $x^2 + 1$.

Comment: @User that is not a field, since $x^2+1=(x+1)^2$ is reducible over $\mathbb Z_2$. A better example is $$ \mathbb Z_2[x]/(x^2+x+1)$$

Comment: @ASKASK oops, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @R.Sherlock please see ASKASK’s comment.

Comment: @R.Sherlock in general, to construct a field of order $p^n$, you may consider $$\mathbb Z_p[x]/(f(x))$$where $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$. This was my line of thinking, and for some reason I didn’t pay attention to the fact that $x^2+1$ is actually reducible in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$.

Comment: @ASKASK Thank you!

Comment: @User thank you for your line of thinking, i got that.

Answer (score 3):

The multiplicative group of $F$ has order $3$ and so $x^3=1$ for all $x\ne 0$. Now
$$
0 = x^3-1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)
$$
Therefore, if $x\ne1$, then $x^2+x+1=0$ and $x^2=-x-1=x+1$, because $-1=1$.

Comment: Thank you , your way is really good. And can you show me a concrete example of a field with order 4?

Comment: @R.Sherlock You can see addition and multiplication tables at [Wikipedia: Finite field § Field with four elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Field_with_four_elements).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thank you!